# Unity 2D distance between two objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to get the distance between the two objects, but my script always returns 1, even when I am changing the distance between the objects.

Code:

```
Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position)
```

The GameObject "player" is assigned in the Unity Editor, that's not the problem.
This script is in one of the objects and it should return the distance between itself and the player.

Can somebody help please.

Thanks

Comment: What are the values of `transform.position` and `player.transform.position`?

Comment: The GameObject with script is on 0 0 0, and when I was testing I put the "player" on 10 0 0 / 5 0 0 etc.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I suppose that the transformations modify the positions.

Comment: The positions are as I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, and the issue might be related to something else in your project. Here are a few things you can check:

**Ensure Proper Execution Context**

Could you confirm that the script containing this code is attached to a GameObject that is active in the scene? If the script is not running, it won't calculate distances correctly.

**Debugging with Logs**

Add some debug logs to verify that the positions are being retrieved correctly.

```
Debug.Log("Object Position: " + transform.position);
Debug.Log("Player Position: " + player.transform.position);
```

**Verify 2D Environment**

Double-check that your game is set up as a 2D project. If it's a 3D environment, you should use Vector3.Distance instead.

**Check for Updates**

Ensure that you're not inadvertently modifying the positions of the objects elsewhere in your code.

**Inspect the Objects in Unity Editor**

In the Unity Editor, select the objects involved and make sure their positions are what you expect.

**Try Debugging with Gizmos (Optional)**

You can use Gizmos to draw a line between the objects in the Scene view. Add the following method to your script:

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, player.transform.position);
}
```

This can help visually confirm the positions.

Comment: Hey, I tried what you wrote and found an issue. When I tried to print the position, it showed that the object position is 0 1 0 (it is on 0 0 0) and player position on 0 0 0 (the player position in editor was completly different, I put him on 5 0 2 and started the game). Do you know how is this fixable, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After some checking I somehow fixed it, idk how, but thanks for help.